# Is there a macro or function in order to use goal seek / solver on an entire column?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a column which has a max value of 280 (e.g.A1:20), which is changed by several inputs (B1:20, C1:20, D1:20) and often falls lower than 280, but one of the inputs (D1:20) it would be useful to max out and therefore increase the value of A1:20 to 280. The value of A1 relays on a equation with variables which do not change, so only B1,
C1,  D1 do change.

I have obviously used goal seek to increase the value of A1 by varying D1 whilst keeping B1, C1 the same, but I would like to replicate this for the whole column of A1:20 and D1:20. Additionally I would like this to run until E1:20 = 2 which is another calculated value and relies on all the cells apart from A1:20, and some external variables.

Is this type of thing possible within formular say IF(A1=280, B1 * C1 * D1, 'goalseek....), or will it have to macros.

If further clarification is needed drop a comment and I will add an example sheet.

I have only tried goal seek on the initial cell I wanted to change, unfortunately I wouldn't know what else to try.

Comment: Some sample data would do nicely here just to visualize what you are trying.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GpGLxc8vr9fjXsrGLiehsNHc9A2Cwnk1/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=117589896964011409041&rtpof=true&sd=true                                      t                                                                                                                                                      This provides an example, with L16:L36 being the column which I want goal seeked with P16:36 to be set to be maxed to 280, until C16:36 is reduced down to 2. Hope you can access this and it works on sheets as its originally a excel doc.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this VBA code which worked well but I am going to further edit.

```
    Sub solve()

    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 16 To 595


   ' solve Macro

     'Reset Solver
      SolverReset


     SolverOk SetCell:="$P$" & i, MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=280, ByChange:="$J$" & i, _
     Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
SolverSolve (True)

     SolverSolve userFinish:=True
     SolverFinish KeepFinal:=1


    Next i


    End Sub
```